# How to determine max IOPS of your application

Tags: sql-server, database, storage

Want to get input from master here. Recently my user asking, what is your maximum IOPS database for your application to be working fine.

Is there anyone have suggestion or recommendation tools to determine this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: IOPS is for storage(I/O Per Second) and number depends on what storage drive you selected for the server... If you have premium Storage then your IOPS will be more. For PaaS db's like SQL Azure Microsoft came up with different metrics which is DTU (Database Throughput Unit) to track IO, Memory and Processing capabilities

Comment: But as a new application how we determine the maximum iops? By doing loadtest?